# Magento2: Re generate css file in pub/static folder

Tags: magento2, css, deploy, static-content-deploy

I have installed Magento 2 and set developer mode, then I have installed one module that contains css and js files. The module works fine and css and js files are rendering from pub/static folder. Now I have made css changes in module directory css file and run command

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

but Magento is not making my new changes in pub/static css files so I'm getting old css file contents. 
Does anyone know how to regenerate the whole css file in pub/static folder?

Comment: FYI: **Magento 2 has a developer mode so you don't have to deploy static content all the time.** I've wasted hours and hours in the past month redeploying static content. So don't be like me, and switch to developer mode (on your local machine.  Your live server should be on production mode)

Comment: why regenerate with different version??? I have an issue with deploy file version not match. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94502/magento2-re-generate-css-file-in-pub-static-folder

Comment: If magento is in developer mode it will create symlinks to the static files but for this to happen you have to have `.htaccess` file in the `pub/static` folder so it knows how to symlink files, if you deleted the pub/static folder that `.htaccess` is missing now

Comment: @NathanMerrill you are so right but most of the dev's don't read documentation and all the answers and still run the static-content:deploy command and what is a bit sad is that some of the companies with account on Stackexchange provide answers like that, waste of time

Comment: I get annoyed every time I see those comments. You should not have to go to developer mode just to deploy small css changes.

Comment: i am having same issues. if you have solution of this question please send me at sarvesht.fantasyworld@gmail.com or post here.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Before deleting **pub/static** make a backup of **pub/static/.htaccess** and restore it again. otherwise your all css and js will show 404 error!

1. Remove `pub/static` (keep the .htaccess backed up and copy it again)
2. Remove `var/cache`
3. Remove `var/composer_home`
4. Remove `var/generation`
5. Remove `var/page_cache`
6. Remove `var/view_preprocessed`
7. Run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: You are perfect MY FRIEND!

Comment: can I complete delete the var folder ? will it regenerate again, because i accidenlty pushed it it to the repo and now it constantly detects changes in the var folder, despite the fact that it is in the .gitignore. While it is in the repo, it will always detect them.

Comment: M2 doesn't make things very developer friendly.

Comment: is there any other solution without removing the folders manually?

Comment: These folders are meant to be automatically generated. You need to understand the di genereration concepts magento is using to understand why deleting these folders is a normal thing to do.  Usually, you would delete them while testing your modules and deployments.  If you are installing modules, and those modules mess up, you just have to fix it.  Also, don't delete the var folder.

Comment: @CarComp no files should ever have to be deleted manually. magento should take care of that. it is very annoying

Comment: U must be new to magento ;)

Comment: I think removing pub/static you lose also the .htaccess file inside that is important to avoid 404 errors, is ok to delete the subfolders of pub/static but that .htaccess should be preserved

Comment: why regenerate with different version??? I have an issue with deploy file version not match. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94502/magento2-re-generate-css-file-in-pub-static-folder

Comment: I am new to "magento". WAT? Is it the official way to update css?

Answer (score 25):

answers here don't mention that you **shouldn't delete the .htaccess** in the pub/static folder.

to delete all files except the .htacces **enter the pub/static directory** and run

```
cd ./pub/static/

find . -depth -name .htaccess -prune -o -delete
cd ..
cd ..
rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/
```

It's important that you go to `./pub/static` *before* running the other commands, otherwise *all* your directories will be deleted!

Comment: why regenerate with different version??? I have an issue with deploy file version not match. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94502/magento2-re-generate-css-file-in-pub-static-folder

Comment: did not work as expectedd

Comment: this command delete all of my directories -_-

Comment: @IzharMehdi did you enter the pub/static directory like it said in the answer?

Comment: yes :D my bad forgot to give full path

Comment: I deleted all files in prod website, didn't enter pub/static directory please add command cd pub/static at the beginning

Comment: this command deleted all  my files in root folder

Answer (score 11):

I have just delete the css files from `pub/static` folder and run the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

It will re generate the same file with latest changes.

Comment: why regenerate with different version??? I have an issue with deploy file version not match. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94502/magento2-re-generate-css-file-in-pub-static-folder

Answer (score 10):

### Simple way 1

In the Magento Admin. Go to `System > Tools > Cache Management` and click **Flush Static Files Cache**.

### Simple way 2

If you just changed the css file **which already existing**, what you need to do is **just** delete the corresponding file in `pub/static`, then when you refresh the page, it will generate the new version css file. It works in the **developer mode**.

---

### Notice

1. When you create new file, rather than modifying an existing file, you may also need to clear the cache, `php bin/magento cache:flush`.
2. **Default mode** and **developer mode** doesn't need [deploy static view files](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html), because of static files being dynamically generated rather than materialized. (Reference: [About Magento modes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html))
3. In **production mode**, you need deploy static files and clean cache by running `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and `bin/magento cache:flush`.

Comment: it's not working for me

Answer (score 9):

As the question is for **`js and css`** update in **Magento 2** in **developer** mode.

1. **Updating the JS** in your respected module,before refreshing page the same file  from `pub/static/frontend/namespace/theme/ ... module/js/...` delete it so after page refresh fresh JS file will generate in pub folder.
2. **Updating the CSS** in your respected module, do the pt 1.
3. **Updating Less** file

Setup theme in magento `...\dev\tools\grunt\configs\themes.js`

Clone any one theme example **luma theme** to your theme and assign a name suppose **xyz**

```
xyz: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Magento/luma',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    }
```

In root folder change file name : **Gruntfile.js.sample** to **Gruntfile.js**

In root folder change file name : **package.json.sample** to **package.json**

Need to have **grunt** in you site folder else **install via npm**

Open command prompt with **administrator permission**

Go to site folder in CMD &  hit command `grunt exec:theme` for first time after deploy the theme

Then `grunt less:theme`  every time if we do any changes in less

If you are doing frequently changes in less use `grunt watch` so it will automatic hit `grunt less:theme`

> Note  :  You might get **Symlink** error so go to file
>   `.../app/etc/di.xml` and comment out or remove code (below code ) in
>   you local till development done, don't push chnaged code of this file
>   to server, it only required in  local if need.

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```

Answer (score 9):

There is one important note to make about this question that most of the answers don't specifically point out. In your case (with the set up you are using) the reason your CSS changes aren't getting picked up when you regenerate the CSS into the `pub/static` folder is you aren't removing the content of the `var/view_preprocessed` director. Inside this directory there are cached version of your CSS that are pulling into the `pub/static` folder when you run the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command.

So when you recompile, Magento will first look to the `var/view_preprocessed` folder for the cached CSS. If this folder is empty, it will look to the theme files and pull that CSS for compilation.

These setting are configurable, so there are a lot of way to get to your destination that will change the path you need to take. But for the solution to your specific setup:

1. Remove the files from the `pub/static` folder: `rm -rf pub/static/*`
2. Remove the files from the `var/view_preprocessed` folder: `rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*`
3. Recompile the pub static folder: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
4. Clear cache is it's turned on: `php bin/magento cache:clean`
5. Refresh the browser.

Comment: would be nice if magento2 would make symlinks to those affected files in developer mode, then changes in those module files where visible on the fly

Comment: It does, but i haven't gotten my head around the when and the how, os i didn't bring this up in the answer. There are global config files that can set this in your di.xml (`app/etc/di.xml`) file. But i have had mixed results while testing. There is a little more here in the second answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116605/magento-2-symbolic-links-to-pub-static-files

Answer (score 7):

do not forget to run the `grunt exec:theme`, `grunt less:theme` commands where `theme` is the theme you declared in the `themes.js` file from the config folder of grunt ( all this is in the developer guide ) and when you have magento in developer mode you shouldn't run the static deploy command, `Magento2` works with `Symlinks`

Comment: "when you have magento in developer mode you shouldn't run the static deploy command" <- This was extremely helpful to me. Thanks! I just deleted the contents of the pub/static directory (except for .htaccess of course), refreshed the page and symliks to my css files were automatically generated. Now I can edit them on the fly. Who said Magento 2 is not dev friendly?! Just need to know how to use it I guess.

Comment: Hi thank you mate, grunt less:default solved the problem

Answer (score 6):

Ok so based on what I have read in various other posts and my personal experience here is the process to regenerate the CSS or any Static Content:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

This will wipe out all the necessary cache/generation/etc files without deleting anything you actually need.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

This will then re-compile the files.  Lastly:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

After the last command everything should be new and fresh, just refresh your page.

***-----  Notes ------***

1) Make sure your file permissions and owner:user group is set correctly before doing this, you may need to speak about these with your sysadmin.

2) If your setup:upgrade command fails it might delete the files and be unable to write the new ones, as was my case due to file permissions.  This can break your site, just iron out the permissions, then re-run the command.

3) I have not found (so far) a way to only re-compile a specific theme or file (would be super helpful if anyone finds a way) without writing a completely custom script

If anyone knows of something better let me know, because 12 minutes of compiling files because I had to make some css changes is extremely poor design in my eyes.

***--- Edit ---***

Magento 2 has Grunt tied into it and this makes refreshing CSS/LESS files infinitely easier if you take the time to configure it.  Most the files are there as .sample files just remove the .sample file extension, configure the themes.js file in /dev/tools/grunt/configs folder.  Then when you need to refresh your LESS files you simply run grunt less:--theme-- from the command line.

Resource:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Comment: Stop providing the php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy method, in developer mode magento has symlinks

Comment: Oh and manually deleting the folders, removing the .htaccess files and others unrelated, and forcing it to rebuild is the better method???  I added a comment about using Grunt, because simply moving your store to developer mode doesn't instantiate all the symlinks and refresh your css on page reload.

Answer (score 6):

Run these commands on your **Magento root** folder:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy ; 
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: Never thought of running a reindex in background 

Comment: Is it me or are these Magento 1 commands in answer to a Magento 2 question?

Comment: There are no Magento 1 commands, they are from Magento 2

Answer (score 5):

Remove folder that contain your theme in pub/static/frontend
clear cache
You can use grunt to watch apply stylesheets. Read [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html)

Comment: why regenerate with different version??? I have an issue with deploy file version not match. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94502/magento2-re-generate-css-file-in-pub-static-folder

Answer (score 5):

1. Remove pub static.
2. Give `pub/static` 777 permission
3. Clear cache.
4. Run: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

You will see new css.

#### NOTE:

Give proper folder and file permission.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: "You will see new css." - I didn't but thank you

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't you just flush static cache in the admin panel and then

```
run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using developer mode.

Then execute following code:

```
chmod -R 777 var generated pub/static
grunt exec:default
grunt less:your_theme_name
```

Refresh the frontend page, These steps solved my problem.

Comment: nice, it really help me thanks

Comment: i am in production mode. can you help me regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

However, you may add the `-f` or `--force` flag to the setup command.

Example:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna drop my wisdom droplet here.

I use a `cache_fly.sh` bash script which basically does:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
start=`date +%s%N`
./magento setup:upgrade && \ 
./magento cache:flush && \ 
./magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
end=`date +%s%N`
runtime=$(bc <<< "scale=9;($end-$start)/1000000000")
echo "" && echo "" && echo -e "\e[34mTOTAL EXECUTION TIME: \e[1m\e[93m$runtime\e[0m"
```

**NOTE:** I've added an echo to show me how many time of my life I've wasted waiting for it to run.
Also `./magento` is a script to do `php bin/magento` or call the same thing inside the docker container, if is docker used you could make yours or point to `php bin/magento` but if you're reading this you should know what I'm talking about, if not, please run asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Little adaptation for my case

```bash
#!/bin/bash
start=`date +%s%N`
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ && \
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/tmp/* var/generation/* pub/static/frontend/* && \
./magento cache:flush && \
./magento setup:upgrade && \
./magento cache:clean && \
./magento s:s:d es_ES en_US -f && \
./magento setup:di:compile && \
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
end=`date +%s%N
runtime=$(bc <<< "scale=9;($end-$start)/1000000000")
echo "" && echo "" && echo -e "\e[34mTOTAL EXECUTION TIME: \e[1m\e[93m$runtime\e[0m"
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was all folder permession , the easy fix is to just do the following:

1- change the /pub folder permission to 777:

```
sudo chmod 777 pub -Rf
```

2- redeploy the site static contents:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

in case u have multi-lang site, write like this:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US ar_SA
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Very Simple Way.

```
cd pub/static
find . -depth -name .htaccess -prune -o -delete
cd ../..
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

[Please read the latest Magento document!](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)