# Magento After installing, images does not working correct; no graphics

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm new on Magento . 
I have started on Magento 2.1 . 
The problem is that when i'm trying to install Magento in my localhost (Xampp) the images doesn't load correctly 
I think it's not even inside my project because i tried to follow the directory and there are no images in it  . 
anyone facing something like this before  ?

Answer (score 1):

run below command and check.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following in the command prompt:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

It will load necessary css and images. Then try logging into admin. It works.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the following link to regenerate the static content in the proper manner which will solve your problem: [Magento2 Regenerate full static content](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102230/magento2-regenerate-full-static-content/141233#141233)