# Latest css changes not get updated in pub/static folder - magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, css, static-content

I installed magento 2.0.1 and working in developer mode.Now the problem is whenever I change css its not get reflect into pub/static folder . I could refer this [Magento2: Re generate css file in pub/static folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94502/magento2-re-generate-css-file-in-pub-static-folder) but no luck. Before its working fine, Now only its getting problem.

**folder permission :** 755 and also try 777 but no luck

anything we can do apart from this

**note:** I am wondering, whenever deploy static content that time also not generated my new updated css old css only getting load and also when I delete any css from my theme pub/static folder its not get generated but, before it get generate after loading page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple thing which could cause this problem is cache. First thing to try is to refresh and clear magento as well as browser cache.

Comment: Thank for the reply, Already done this but not working bro(bin/magento cache:clean) and flush cache from admin  and remove total var folder also

Comment: OMG! its a browser issue after open with firefox private window its working fine as well as taken my css changes and generated into my pub/static folder also. Yes you are right cache only the problem, private window does not capture cache. it eats my 2 hour

Comment: God. I was mad because of this. I thought it was an magento issue. In incognito it works. Thank god.

Comment: for me it was browsers cache

Comment: Without going incognito, Go to inspect in chrome then go to Network tab, and then Mark on Disable cache.
Browser will get the latest content.