# Override CSS - Magento 2.0.6 (Resolved)

Tags: magento2, overrides, less-css, magento-2.0.6

Even tough I can add new custom css files, I'm unable to override the current styles.

I have done as described here but my button remains as original color blue:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html

Is there any step missing from this guidance?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your custom theme applied at all? Also, try the steps described here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html#troubleshooting-if-the-changes-do-not-get-applied

Answer (score 1):

delete all folder inside `<magento-root>/var/*` because var/* folder cached old css style.

delete var/* is not a problem because when page load its automatically get generated.

then clear you browser cache, load your page.

suppose still the problems remain please refer the below links.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454314/simple-style-change-does-not-apply/36510694#36510694

[Magento2: Re generate css file in pub/static folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94502/magento2-re-generate-css-file-in-pub-static-folder)

have good luck.

Comment: It worked after removing the entire var/. Thanks man!