# Magento 2.1 CDN static/media base URLs - getting 404 for all files

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm trying to change the base urls for static and media files to the URL of my CDN however when I change them, I get 404 not found for all images/media/static/css/js

All files and content is available on the CDN url as I can go to a file directly by going to e.g.

```
http://CDNURL/pub/static/frontend/edgesystems/idca/en_GB/css/styles.css
```

Yet the URL of the file (and all others) that is trying to load on the site is like this:

```
http://CDNURL/frontend/edgesystems/idca/en_GB/css/styles.css
```

Its missing the /pub/static/ bit out

I am currently in developer mode and have tried doing the change in di.xml as per [Magento 2 : Symbolic links to pub/static files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116605/magento-2-symbolic-links-to-pub-static-files)

I have a .htaccess file in /pub/static but maybe it is incorrect in there?

Does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: I can add in my base urls for static and media like so and it seems to work alot better i.e. http://CDNURL/pub/static/ & http://CDNURL/pub/media/ - however product images and theme icons do not seem to work - are these the correct format for the urls or should it work with just     http://CDNURL/ ?