# backend and theme folder and not being rebuilt

Tags: magento2

I've cleared the the static and cache folders as recommended here -

[Magento2: Re generate css file in pub/static folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94502/magento2-re-generate-css-file-in-pub-static-folder)

But now backend and my theme folder are missing from static, so I'm getting lots of missing files?

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

doesn't help?

Answer (score 0):

I also deleted the .htaccess file in the static folder. Added that back in static folder and it started again - everything started to work :)

Reference - https://community.magento.com/t5/Theming-Layout-Design-Questions/Static-files-for-custom-theme-not-being-generated/td-p/39563

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin Section Cache Management click **Flush Static File Cache** and run

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

command your theme Folder Re Generate your theme folder in Pub Static.