# magento 2 css is not added to head element

Tags: magento2, css, js-css

I develop a **theme** extending **blank theme**.

I mainly add some css to the _extend.less file, but now I need to add some 3rd party css to the theme.

I added the css-s to the proper directory.

```
/dev_magento/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css
```

And indicated the source in the

```
/dev_magento/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

After all done

deleted `pub/static` , `var/view_preprocessed/` directories and cleaned and flushed the caches.

However the css is not available, not even seen on the page source from the browser. js files also unavailable.

The google font is working. I can not see what can be the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,   maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <css src="css/example.css"/>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
            <script src="js/simples.js">
        <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <css src="css/bootstrap.css">
            <css src="css/kremvarazs_home_page.css">
    <link src='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,900,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' src_type="url"/>
<link src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css' src_type="url">
</head>
```

Thank you for advising and looking into this problem

Answer (score 0):

All tag must be **closed** or **self closed** in layout **xml** file. You are not closed some of the **script** and css **tag**.

For local css & js:

```
<css src="css/example.css"/>
<script src="js/simples.js"/>
```

For Third party css & js [type-URL]

```
<css src='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,900,500'  src_type="url"/>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" src_type="url" />
```

Still css not available in page source, follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/94506/36463) for generate css file in pub/static folder.